# Finding the harmonic conjugate given real part

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I have $\Im(z)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$ and need to find the harmonic conjugate of it.
I'm looking at SO question and its answer [Showing that $u(x, \, y) = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$ is harmonic without computing partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875186/showing-that-ux-y-lnx2-y2-is-harmonic-without-computing-partial)

The answer there is $2\ln z$ but in the book I have it's $2i\ln z$. So what's missing?

Comment: $2 Log \, z$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ with real part $\ln (x^{2}+y^{2})$ where Log denotes the principal branch of logarithm. I have not seen people wiring ln for principle logarithm.

Comment: In what region are you trying to find the harmonic conjugate? Your function does not have a harmonic conjugate in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: actually this is the imaginary part, sorry